# Store List in table columns

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have table performance and hours. One performnace can be played many times at certain hours. One to Many relations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "performance_type")
@Data
public class PerformanceType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer performanceTypeId;
    @Column(length=127)
    private String performOptions;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "performance")
@Data
public class Performance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer performanceId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "performance")
    private List<Hours> performanceHours = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

In database hibernate create table hours that have performanceId thas have only one value. How i may insert list values that performance with id 1,4,7 are played in the same time. That i need additoinal table hours_performance that store hourId and perfomanceId?

Comment: What actually issue you are facing. What mapping you have added in Hours. @ManyToOne?

Comment: Yes if hour value is the id of hours table, then you need a separate table to save performance-hours relationship. It will be many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the relationship you want to achieve is (according to my understanding) many-to-many, you do indeed need a third table mapping hours to relationships. [Here is a very good example.](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-many-to-many) You will need to set up your third table with two foreign keys to the two tables you want to connect.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "performance")
@Data
public class Performance {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer performanceId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "hours_performance", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "performance_id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "hour_id") }
    )
    private List<Hours> performanceHours = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "hours")
@Data
public class Hours {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer hourId;
    ZonedDateTime time;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "performanceHours")
    private List<Performance> performances;
}
```